# Jquery get links where id is empty

Tags: jquery

I need to change the font color on the first link.

```
<a href="/default.aspx" class="content">Frontpage</a>    
<a href="/default.aspx" class="content" id="product_randomnumber_link">Frontpage</a>
```

But I just can't figure out a way to only select the first a.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$('a:not([id])')` or `$('a:not([id]):first')`.

Comment: Thx got it working with $('.content:not([id])').css('color', '#FFFFFF');

Answer (score 1):

This might work :

```
$("a").not("a[id]").css("color","#F0F");
```

Comment: I think the `a` in your `not` bit is redundant, but nevertheless, it ought to work.

Comment: `.attr()` ? I guess you mean `.css()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.content[id=""]:first').css('color','#fff');
```

Comment: `id=""` does not work for me if there is no id attribute at all. (chrome)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.content[id=]').css('color', '#ffffff');
```